# What to do if two classes in same namespace gets included in two different libraries in C#

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

I have a program (Main application which consists of legacy code ) which consumes a library. Sadly, both main application and the library uses a classes (with same name and same properties) called `Softwares.SoftwareXSD`. When I use the class defined inside `Softwares.SoftwareXSD`, the main program complains about ambiguity. However, Visual Studio is saying that it is smart enough to choose within the duplicates by displaying a green underline under the class name. I believe this is not a good approach.

Is there any any problem with this? What is the best workaround for this situation?

The problem is that some classes in the XSD is specific to main application and some is specific to the library but these classes are linked with each other using references.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you have two classes `Softwares.SoftwareXSD` in different assemblies (main application and library) whose fully-qualified name is identical.

To resolve this, go to Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, expand "References", right click on the reference to your library and select properties.

In "Aliases" replace "global" by some other alias, e.g. "library".

You can now disambiguate the references as follows:

```
global::Softwares.SoftwareXSD // is in the main application
library::Softwares.SoftwareXSD // is in the library
```

Nevertheless, I'd still recommend you to choose unique names for your classes.

Comment: It would appear that you also need to add: "extern alias xxxx;" to the top of the code file in order to use a reference alias in this manner. (E.g. in this case: "extern alias library;")

Answer (score 3):

You can use an alias for the library namespace to disambiguate the members:

```
using XSD = Softwares.SoftwareXSD;
```

then later:

```
XSD.SomeClass.SomeLibraryCall();
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The Softwares.SoftwareXSD[this file is duplicated in main application and library] is contained in both modules. how can i make sure the compiler is seeing only one copy?

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler is complaining about "disambiguous reference" because you have two namespaces with same class name and you happen to  have using statements for both the namespaces (in your case) you can get away with 
`global` keyword.

ex: `using LegacySoftwareXSD =  global::LegacySoftwares.Softwares.SoftwareXSD;`

Comment: Thanks,Used as you said. compiles fine.but the green underline[warning] still prevails.

Comment: It says that the two XSD's exist in different modules and they are in conflict. However, the compiler is choosing the one defined in the Main application. While compiling i am getting the following error  Error 565 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'out Software.SoftwareXSD.SoftInfo[] ..\trunk\SoftwareXSD\SoftwareXSD.cs(3698)]' to 'out SoftwaresSoftwareXSD.SoftInfo[] [..\trunk\liCCManager.dll]' ..\trunk\WepaGui\MainWindow.xaml.cs 859 71 SoftwareApplication

Comment: after adding using LegacySoftwareXSD = global::LegacySoftwares.Softwares.SoftwareXSD; statement and using LegacySotwareXSD type name to create instances of SoftwareXSD under legacy namespace. ex: LegacySoftwareXSD xsd1 = new LegacySoftwareXSD();

Comment: Thanks for your support Vijay. I decided to copy the code to the main application from the library.